# how to use FetchType.EAGER

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I'm not able to load, from DB, an object with its relative mapped objects. Probably my "map system" is wrong.

When saving an object (and its relative mapped objects) in the DB everything is ok, so the objects seem to be correctly mapped.

**Utente** is my "master" object

```
   public class Utente implements Serializable{
        .......    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id_utente", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer idUtente;    
        .......
```

I haven another object called `Autenticazione`, where I link  `Autenticazione` to `Utente`

```
public class Autenticazione implements Serializable{    
    ....
    @OneToOne(targetEntity=Utente.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="utente", referencedColumnName="id_utente")    
    private Utente utente;
    ...
```

When I get from the db a `Utente` object, I want to get also its `Autenticazione` object. I tried some code (not posted here to avoid confusion), but i didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an association from Utente to Autenticazione too:

```
public class Utente implements Serializable{
    .......    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_utente", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer idUtente;    
    .......

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente")
    private Autenticazione autenticazione;
```

Make sure you set both sides of the associations with a helper method like one you should add to Utente:

```
    public void addAutenticazione(Autenticazione autenticazione) {
        autenticazione.setUtente(this);
        this.autenticazione = autenticazione;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you man, this is what I missed. I just added@OneToOne(mappedBy = "utente") private Autenticazione autenticazione; and it seems to work, even without the addAutenticazione method

Comment: The `addAutenticazione` method is for consistency reasons. Whenever you have a bi-directional relationship, you need to set both sides of the association.